# How to validate a related entity still exists in database, on form submit?

Tags: database, validation, symfony, symfony-forms

I have an entity `Activity`, with a CRUD in one part of my app.
In another part of the app, I have a form representing a `UserData` entity, with a `@ManyToOne` relation to `Activity`.

When submitting this form, I want to validate that chosen `Activity` still exists in database (because of CRUD, it could be deleted between the form loading and the form submit).

I dug a lot into symfony core files, and found that this validation is done the Form component, in `viewToNorm()` method which throw a `TransformationFailedException`, which is then silenced by the `submit()` method :

```
public function submit($submittedData, $clearMissing = true)
{
    try {
        [...]

        // Normalize data to unified representation
        $normData = $this->viewToNorm($viewData);

        [...]
    } catch (TransformationFailedException $e) {
        $this->transformationFailure = $e;

        // If $viewData was not yet set, set it to $submittedData so that
        // the erroneous data is accessible on the form.
        // Forms that inherit data never set any data, because the getters
        // forward to the parent form's getters anyway.
        if (null === $viewData && !$this->config->getInheritData()) {
            $viewData = $submittedData;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to build a custom Constraint with a custom Validator, but it doesn't work, because in case of Transformation failure, Symfony reset the data to it's original form value, so my validator receive a `NULL` value instead of the deleted entity.

I could build a `DataTransformer` and catch this exception manually, but `DataTransformer` are not meant to perform validation.

Is there any other way to check a relation still exists in database and at the end, customize the message displayed in FormError ?

Comment: Well, I know the question is old but I am interested to give an answer... But I really don´t understand what is the goal here. Lets go through an edit flow: 1. We call the `action` method, Symfony fills the form fields with the property values including the form field for the `Activity` class. 2. When submitting the form Symfony uses the form field values to set the entity objects property, can´t find an appropriate `Activity` and passes `NULL` to your custom validator, right?

Comment: So you did know that the entity doesn't exist because your Validator got `NULL` and you could have returned an according message...  Thats what you wanted, right? Or are you paranoid and want to check yourself if the `Activity` still exists in the database?